# Inverse linear Transformation in Functional Notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the Linear transformation 
$T: P_2(R) -> P_2(R)$

$B=$${1, x, x^2} $
$$T(f(x))=x^{2}f''(x)+xf'(x)+f(x)$$

Now I find the matrix representation of the transformation

$
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 5
  \end{array} } \right]$
and then I find the Inverse of $
   A^{-1}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1/5
  \end{array} } \right]$

But I now I am confused on how to convert $A^{-1}$ back into functional notation, I tried brute forcing it and failed.

Comment: With respect to what basis, in what space?

Comment: $T: P_2(R) -> P_2(R)$ and Basis $B=$${1, x, x^2} $